# Is there a way to reduce the build time when using compiled ASP.NET MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, razor

I've enabled the compiling of our ASP.NET MVC views.  I knew this would add to the build time, but I had no idea it would make compilation 20 times slower!  I realize that the reason could be due to inefficiency bugs in msbuild or the MVC SDK, but I'm hoping there's something *we* can do differently so it isn't so incredibly slow.

Have any of you found any tricks to reduce the compile time of ASP.NET MVC razor views?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/04/15/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior.aspx
Though I must admit I've never tried this for MVC view precompilation.

Comment: Great link.  Unfortunately, it seems to only apply to on-the-fly compilation of pages when they're deployed to a site, not to pre-compiled views.