# Visual Studio publish dialog taking a long time to appear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We have a fairly large ASP.NET MVC solution (around 45 projects) and when I try and publish (web), the publish dialog takes around 5-10 mins to appear.  Once it appears the publish itself is pretty quick and works fine.  This happens on any server I point the publish to.

Does anyone else have this issue? or know of any reason why this might be happening?

We are using VS2015 (although we also had this problem before when using 2012/13).

I've searched around but can't find anything relevant.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997505/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-build-time-when-using-compiled-asp-net-mvc-views

Comment: Thanks Jamie, but it's not actually the building that's the problem. It builds fairly quickly. There seems to be no activity going on during the 5-10min delay - in face Visual Studio says 'not responding' in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, with the same issue [Visual Studio Publish Web Dialogue takes excessive time to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846284/visual-studio-publish-web-dialogue-takes-excessive-time-to-load/33057238)

> TL;DR: As a workaround for this problem, find your DbContext class which inherit from IdentityDbContext<> and change base class constructor from base("DefaultConnection") to base("DefaultConnection", false) and do a full rebuild on your solution. That will disable checking against Entity 1.0.0 which causes timeouts when run from Publish Web.